# Asking a question in a formal and clever form

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to say that, because [you're a student] of Maryland university, I thought you live there, but I want to say it in a clever and also formal form.

How should I say this:

"I thought you are in Maryland"

Comment: On a side note, you may want to clarify whether you are referring to the [University of Maryland](http://www.umd.edu/), a [university of Maryland](http://www.usmd.edu/), or any [university in Maryland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_Maryland).

Comment: Clever remarks are rarely formal, and vice versa. That's one reason there **are** formal remarks -- to avoid the necessity of thinking, especially clever thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your being a student of Maryland University, made me think that you belong to Maryland.

Comment: thank you very much for your response, It is about a postdoc. I don't know whether he has finished or not. Is this sentence correct? "Your postdoc of Maryland University made me think that you are in Maryland." (Is it formal? I also I want to add sense of humor for my mistake)

Comment: I believe, Yes it's more than ok.

Comment: Yes, but to be idiomatic you need to say *belonged* - *..made me think that you belonged to Maryland*. The verb tenses in this instance need to agree. You could say *...makes me think that you belong...*

Comment: Wait, what? Since when is living somewhere described as belonging to that place?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to say something lighthearted regarding your assumption about where someone doing post-doctoral studies at the University of Maryland must be living, you could say this:

> Since you are doing your post-doc work at the University of Maryland, I assumed that you were living in the state—because Terrapins generally don't move so fast!

The joke here is that the University of Maryland's sports teams are called the [Terrapins](http://www.umterps.com/), and a [terrapin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamondback_terrapin) is a kind of turtle.

But if the person you are writing to to is doing post-doc work at Johns Hopkins University in Baltimore, you'll have to come up with a different joke, because the sports teams there are called the [Blue Jays](http://www.hopkinssports.com/).

Answer (score -1):

In light of the fact that you attend Maryland University, I assumed you were a native Marylandian.

Comment: [Marylandian?](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Marylandian%2CMarylander&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3)